# Windbg: Breakpoint SOS, or SOSEX.DLL name of the method

Tags: windbg, sos, sosex

While debugging with SOS or SOSEX in managed code, I can set breakpoints using !mbm *!*GetSubscription for example, is there any way to get the method name?

Example:
bp 8373772 ".printf \"methodname\";gc".

The idea is to have the name of the methods executed similar like wt -l command does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!sosex.mln` to get the name of whatever, if any, managed object, method, etc. Is located at a given address.

Comment: You can also use `!mbp <address>`